# How do I set a variable for the file browser input to be passed on to be opened and displayed via print?

Tags: python, yaml, pysimplegui

I'm doing a self-exercise for PySimpleGUI. I am creating a GUI for loading a YAML file and having it printed via print(data). I'm just not sure how I can pass the file path from sg.InputText(key="-FILE_Path-") to be opened. Thanks!

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import yaml
from yaml.loader import SafeLoader
import os

working_directory = os.getcwd()

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Shoose your yaml file:")],
    [sg.InputText(key="-FILE_PATH-"),
    sg.FileBrowse(initial_folder=working_directory, file_types=[("YAML Files","*.yaml")])],
    [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Exit()]
]

window = sg.Window("File Loader", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    elif event == "Submit":
        with open("-FILE_PATH-") as f:
            data = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
            print(data)

window.close()
```

I've modified it but not sure if i added the suggested fix correctly.

I added it like this, but im still getting the :
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-FILE_PATH-' error –`

Heres updated code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import yaml
from yaml.loader import SafeLoader
import os

working_directory = os.getcwd()

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Shoose your yaml file:")],
    [sg.InputText(key="-FILE_PATH-"),
    sg.FileBrowse(initial_folder=working_directory, file_types=[("YAML Files","*.yaml")])],
    [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Exit()]
]

window = sg.Window("File Loader", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    values["-FILE_PATH-"]
    
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    elif event == "Submit":
        with open("-FILE_PATH-") as f:
            data = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
            print(data)

window.close()
```

Comment: You can get the content of "-FILE_PATH-" Input element by `values["-FILE_PATH-"]` after `event, values = window.read()`.

Comment: I added it like this, but im still getting the : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-FILE_PATH-' error

Comment: while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    values["-FILE_PATH-"]
    
   ' if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    elif event == "Submit":
        with open("-FILE_PATH-") as f:
            data = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
            print(data)

window.close()

Comment: `with open(values["-FILE_PATH-"]) as f:` or `file_path = values["-FILE_PATH-"]; with open(file_path) as f:`